# Does sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a brick the system if it is interrupted?

Tags: apt, 20.04, dpkg

After running `sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a` my system powered off and will not boot anymore. Here is the exact order of events:

1. I ran a normal apt upgrade
2. dpkg was interrupted, fix with `sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a`
3. waiting
4. Power outage, system suddenly shuts down
5. System refuses to boot up

Just want to know if dpkg reconfigure messes with my ssd and if it gets interrupted during that, does that leave the ssd in a non readable state?

I tried booting with a live USB and could not find my ssd at all.

Comment: If your SSD is truly dead, and you are speculating about the likely cause, there are many possible causes...and many possible coincidences. If Ubuntu destroyed hardware, we would not use it. If you can *reliably demonstrate* that dpkg, under certain unusual conditions, causes hardware damage...that would be unintended behavior (also known as a bug).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `dpkg --configure` not `dpkg --reconfigure`, since the latter doesn't exist, and `dpkg-reconfigure` lacks a -a option.

In general, power outages while preforming major system administration tasks run the risk of nasty problems.  Configuring a lot of packages is one of those tasks, and (espeically if the packages involved are used in early boot), can result in a broken (though not bricked) system.

However, the worst that should result is an unbootable disk: files not being edited generally shouldn't experience corruption, and under no circumstances should the disk become invisible to a rescue USB.  Now, it's possible (if the stars aligned just wrong) that your power outage hit while, say, GRUB was updating something in the partition table, and wound up hiding the filesystems from the rescue disk.  What does the `lsblk` command output when you run it from the rescue boot?

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    2G  1 loop /rofs
loop1    7:1    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1988
loop2    7:2    0  219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop3    7:3    0   51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/518
loop4    7:4    0 64.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop5    7:5    0 31.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11036
sda      8:0    1 28.7G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    1 28.7G  0 part /cdrom

Comment: sorry for the formatting, but in short, my 512GB SSD does not show up here

Comment: In future, you can use a pastebin to dump text data like that.  It's much quicker, and preserves important formatting.  Are any wires in your computer lose? Any messages in the system log about a hard drive error?

Even with a severe issue, the hard drive should still show up on lsblk.